# How to set maximum available size for JApplet?

Tags: java, javascript, swing, applet, japplet

I am porting my desktop Swing application to an applet. The following code works perfect for `JFrame` entity to set a maximum available window size, considering a task bar.

```
GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
Rectangle bounds = env.getMaximumWindowBounds();
frame.setMaximizedBounds(bounds);
frame.setPreferredSize(bounds.getSize());
frame.setLocation(0, 0);
```

In Eclipse Run Configurations -> My Applet -> Parameters I can select Width and Height or if applet is run from browser one would have to do:

```
<applet code="myJApplet" width="800" height="480">
```

But I would like to be able to set size dynamically depending on screen resolution. How would it be possible?

Comment: what if you set width="80%" ?

Comment: @StanislavL, at least in Eclipse Applet Viewer I cannot set values with %

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov: Why wait? A [hybrid](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12449949/230513) keeps your options open.

Comment: @trashgod, thanks for links. Have to learn about hybrids. It is a pity you haven't noted about it couple of days ago [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066898/how-to-organize-code-to-build-applet-and-application-easily)

Comment: @JoopEggen, "with noscript 800x600" what does it mean, I don't understand..

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov: I think it means if  JavaScript is blocked by a add-on in the browser, like NoScript, use hard-coded values.

Comment: @JoopEggen, makes sense, if you want you can post java skip solution and I would accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found it here: http://andylangton.co.uk/articles/javascript/get-viewport-size-javascript/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var w=window,d=document,e=d.documentElement,g=d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],x=w.innerWidth||e.clientWidth||g.clientWidth,y=w.innerHeight||e.clientHeight||g.clientHeight;
//-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on this previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14066939/230513), you may want to adopt a [hybrid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12449949/230513) approach, which offers additional deployment options via [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info). Your focus should be on developing a `Container` that functions well at any initial size, while avoiding [common traps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12532237/230513). Use `java.util.Preferences` to retain geometry that's under your control, and adapt when it's not. The details depend on the actual content, but the problem is at least well encapsulated.

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaScript, with noscript 800x600. Note, this takes much memory. Though a bit troublesome, maybe better go for a Java Webstart application.

noscript is a tag `<noscript>(static html content)</noscript>` in which you can put conditional HTML - when JavaScript is blocked. With JS you can have a full dynamic solution, in the noscript have a fixed size solution.

Comment: oh, I have meant javascript code which would generate proper size, sorry for confusion.

Comment: That I meant too. But JS can be disabled, and then a minimal functionality would be nice, hence the mention of noscript. Never mind.

Comment: Well, my point is that if you post complete solution of html-page with java script code then it would be definitely the best answer.